# Cakephp 3.x how the get the session_id

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies, cakephp-3.0

In PHP, To get the session id, we have to use like this: `session_id();`

How can I get the id in Cakephp 3.x?

Comment: $this->Session->id(); should do the trick

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is the cakephp 2.x way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access session id as below,

```
$this->request->session()->id()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But only when I use `session_start();` Tis can't be normal?

Comment: @Joost Just have a look at the docs: **http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Session.html#_id** Unlike some other methods, `Session::id()` does no auto start the session, so if hasn't been started before (being it implicitly or explicitly), you'll have to start it manually, but _not_ using `session_start()`!, but [`Session::start()`](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Network.Session.html#_start) (no, that's not a static method).

Comment: **CakePHP 3.8** update: `$this->request->getSession()->id()`

Comment: isnt it $this->getRequest->getSession()->id() ?

Comment: no, it is $this->getRequest()->getSession()->id()